# Ways of representing frequency of updates as a graph?

Tags: charts, graph

I want to create a graph representing the frequency of updates to a site (for example, how often I have posted to my blog over the past 5 years). One obvious way to do this is to plot "number of entries posted per month" for the past 60 months, but this feels unsatisfying. Should I be looking at using something like a rolling average instead? What are good visialisation techniques for displaying this kind of data?

Comment: Perhaps you can indicate what is unsatisfying about the obvious way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

- rolling average
- instead of plotting the number of posts plot the time (or rolling mean time) between posts
- if it's something that may have an annual / seasonal component, try plotting it on a circular / spiral plot where r is the datum and theta is the month, day of month, day of year, or whatever scaled appropriately.  Some interesting things to plot for r might be

  - number of posts in an interval
  - cumulative posts (giving you a spiral)
  - length of post, (giving each theta it's own exact value, not aggregating)
- you might also want to look at a scatter plot, with something like length of post on x, time since prior post + time to next post on y, and the age of the datum as the size, gray level or color of the point (fading out the oldest ones)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [radar chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) (or circular area chart) would be a good bet. Take a look at the excellent [Choosing a good chart](http://extremepresentation.typepad.com/blog/2006/09/choosing_a_good.html) post and PDF chart-selecting-guide over at the [Extreme Presentation(tm) Method](http://extremepresentation.typepad.com/blog/) site.

Comment: In addition, the Google Chart API can easily generate radar charts: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/